# Stick the bar to footer of the container

Tags: html, css

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yet0xgat/2/), I am trying to keep the bar always to bottom-left even if the user scrolls the container. Currently, if I scroll the container, the bar moves along instead of being sticked to the footer always.

Though it seems to be the default behavior, I wasn't aware of this. So, any explanation would be really helpful. (*My expectation was that it will be sticked to the bottom of the container*).

Things to consider:

- The bar should come over the horizontal scroll bar of the container, when resized horizontally. (*which is happening currently*)
- The bar should be always at the bottom of the container. (*not happening*)

```css
.parent {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: tomato;
  overflow: auto;
}
.content {
  height: 18000px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
.bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="bar">BAR</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited after giving this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31319603/1577396).
I ended up using javascript.

```
var stickToBottom = function (parent) {
    var bar = parent.querySelector('.bar');
    var top = bar.offsetTop;
    parent.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
        var el = e.currentTarget;
        bar.style.bottom = -el.scrollTop + "px";
        bar.style.left = el.scrollLeft + "px";
    });
}
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
stickToBottom(parent);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yet0xgat/26/)

Because I had following factors to consider:

- Scrollbar thickness vary in each browser
- Width of the content inside the container varies based on screen resolutions.
- When scrolling the container horizontally, the bar should be still at bottom-left.

Comment: For me, still your bar comes behind the scroll bar

Comment: @Mr.Alien for me it is working fine in fiddle (_for chrome and firefox_) but not in my project. can you please tell which browser you are testing on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
**CSS**

```
.grand-parent{
  position: relative;

}
.parent {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: tomato; 
}
.content {
  height: 18000px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
.bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">BAR</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't move the bar on top of horizontal scroll when I resize the container horizontally as I mentioned in my question. http://jsfiddle.net/bzdhhda2/

Comment: Use media query to do this

Comment: How could I know when the horizontal scroll will come?

Comment: You added content width as 300px and parent width as 60% so around 530 to 550px device width horizontal scroll come