# Stick the bar always to footer even while animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently here, I asked a question to stick a `bar` element always to bottom-left of the container. It seems not possible using just css. So, I ended up using javascript. Here is the [**Working** Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yet0xgat/11/)

Giving highlights of the previous question:

- Stick the bar element to bottom-left of the container
- The bar should be in bottom-left, even the container is scrolled vertically or horizontally.
- The bar should come over the horizontal scrollbar, if the horizontal scrollbar is present.

The above fiddle works fine and obeys all above cases, even when the window is resized.

Now, I have the same situation but the container will get resized because of animation button click but not window resize.

Since, I am animating for one second, I am calling the same code present in the window resize function while I clicked on the animating button. But doing so is somehow breaking and isn't following the above rules/requirements.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yet0xgat/22/). (*not working*)

Please help.

PS: Here is the link to [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31308946/1577396). (*if someone wants brief understanding*)

Comment: Is this what you desire? http://jsfiddle.net/0gzb1esv/

Comment: @JoelAlmeida No, the bar should move a bit top when there is horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @downvoter please explain your downvote. I will try to edit my post.

Comment: found the problem. inside your `setTimeout()` after defining your `bar` use this: `var top = bar.offsetTop; parent.scrollTop = 300;`. http://jsfiddle.net/hgwLdg5z/ like this?

Comment: @JoelAlmeida That still has the same issues.

Comment: working fine here. after 2 seconds the bar stays on top of the scrollbar.. because of the set timeout delay.. and your fiddle seems to be working here on chrome..

Comment: javascript is unnecessary for this.  just add an inner container and fix the element to the bottom of the topmost one: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/9nao4q04/1

Comment: @JosephMarikle I am not sure where my explanation is not clear. I am telling again and again. that the bar should come on top of the horizontal scrollbar not infront.

Comment: @Mr_Green That is precisely why I was confused.  I interpret "on top" and "should come over the horizontal scrollbar" as meaning layered on top, not above it.  In any case, I would still say use more CSS than javascript.  For the animation, set a timer tick calculates the differenece of clientHeight and offsetHeight.  Then set the bottom to that value. http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/9nao4q04/3/

Comment: @JosephMarikle thanks this is working fine. please post it as answer. (_though I had already solved it_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, I solved it. I was making things complicated. Where there was need of only `bottom` property, I was using `top` and resetting it. Lots of unneccessary action in the code.

Here is the code, which is working fine.

```
$(function () {
    $('.content').width($('body').width() - 50);
});

var stickToBottom = function (parent) {
    var bar = parent.querySelector('.bar');
    var top = bar.offsetTop;
    parent.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
        var el = e.currentTarget;
        bar.style.bottom = -el.scrollTop + "px";
        bar.style.left = el.scrollLeft + "px";
    });
}
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
stickToBottom(parent);

$('.clickme').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Thanks to rlemon for giving a idea in [javascript chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/24355500#24355500).

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yet0xgat/25/)